# How to properly filter items using a CQL expression on a GET /wfs3/collections/{collectionId}/items? endpoint

Tags: qgis, qgis-server, cql-filter, ogc-api, ogc-api-features

I'm trying to filter items at a WFS3 GET endpoint served by a [QGIS Server project](https://github.com/camptocamp/docker-qgis-server) (single layer - single PostGIS table) using the OGC Common Query Language.

While this is working perfectly fine, returning me only those items where `dataset_id=5`:

```
<base_URL>/wfs3/collections/collection1/items.json?dataset_id=5
```

none of the following queries (`<=`) are working:

```
.../items.json?dataset_id<=5
.../items.json?"dataset_id"<=5
.../items.json?filter-lang=cql-text&FILTER:dataset_id<=5
.../items.json?filter-lang=cql-text&FILTER:"dataset_id"<=5
.../items.json?filter-lang=cql-text&FILTER=dataset_id<=5
.../items.json?filter-lang=cql-text&FILTER="dataset_id"<=5
```

*(I replaced `<base_URL>/wfs3/collections/collection1` by `...` for readability)*

even those (`=`) are not working:

```
.../items.json?filter-lang=cql-text&FILTER:dataset_id=5
.../items.json?filter-lang=cql-text&FILTER:"dataset_id"=5
.../items.json?filter-lang=cql-text&FILTER=dataset_id=5
.../items.json?filter-lang=cql-text&FILTER="dataset_id"=5
```

Is there anything I can do to properly filter out all the features with a `dataset_id` lower or equal to `5`?

Hint; the next step would be to filter out those features with a `dataset_id` between `4` (included) and `8` (included). But I'm not having more success for the moment.

Browser: Firefox 96.0.1 (64-bit).

Doc:
Part 1 - Core: https://docs.opengeospatial.org/is/17-069r3/17-069r3.html
Part 3 - Filtering using CQL: https://portal.ogc.org/files/96288

##### EDIT

QGIS Server
Conformance Classes
http://www.opengis.net/spec/ogcapi-features-1/1.0/conf/core
http://www.opengis.net/spec/ogcapi-features-1/1.0/conf/oas30
http://www.opengis.net/spec/ogcapi-features-1/1.0/conf/html
http://www.opengis.net/spec/ogcapi-features-1/1.0/conf/geojson

Comment: What conformance classes https://portal.ogc.org/files/96288#_conformance that server supports?

Comment: Okay, I think I get it. But how exactly would both the CQL conformance classes be referenced by the QGIS Server project at `/wfs3/conformance` if they were available? And could I make them available within QGIS (is there an option to check somewhere?)

Comment: Simple CQL as one class and each supported enhancement separately.

Comment: I think they would be represented using something close these URLs:     `http://www.opengis.net/spec/ogcapi-features-3/0.0/conf/cql-json` and
`http://www.opengis.net/spec/ogcapi-features-3/0.0/conf/cql-text` respectively.

Comment: Those would mean the supported query languages.

Comment: This one supports lots of things https://demo.ldproxy.net/daraa/conformance