# How to enable more Conformance Classes of the OGC API - Features in QGIS Server?

Tags: qgis, qgis-server, ogc-api, ogc-api-features

Follow up on this thread: [How to properly filter items using a CQL expression on a GET /wfs3/collections/{collectionId}/items? endpoint](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/421854/65370)

is it possible to allow more Conformance Classes, e.g. [those related to Part 3 -  Filtering and the Common Query Language (CQL)](https://portal.ogc.org/files/96288#_conformance) in a QGIS Server project?

And if yes, how?

There isn't much documentation here: https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/server_manual/services/ogcapif.html
neither here, which is the docker image I'm currently using: https://github.com/camptocamp/docker-qgis-server

Comment: The traditional "pull requests are welcome" probably applies.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it doesn't seem implemented yet, according to this page:

[image: Screenshot - QGIS Server: status of implemented Conformance Classes]

Source: https://www.ogc.org/resource/products/details/?pid=1611